# Program is only opening the GUI when I'm in debugging mode

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a drop down menu using a string from a file which I;m reading in. That part works. However, I'm trying to build the GUI using `tkinter` and it will only open in debugging mode. When it does open, it works. What is going on?

```
master = Tk()

with open('player_names.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next (plots)
    for row in plots:
        number.append((row[0]))
        first.append(row[1])
        last.append(row[2]) 

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(number[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *number)
w.pack()

def ok():
    print ("value is:" + variable.get())

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

When it works correctly, the GUI opens and there is a little drop down menu with all of the values from `number[]`. It just won't open.

Comment: What are you running to start it, both ways? Maybe you are running it from different working directories so it is not finding your csv.

Comment: @MattClark I'm using Wing. I'm just running it like I always do. I built another GUI with tkinter and it worked just fine.

Comment: Maybe simply adding some logging statements to see the working directory of your application, and if it loaded the file properly?

Comment: @MattClark the file is loading correctly. If I manually define the string, it still wont open when I just run it, but will in debug mode.

Comment: @andrewalmosthasaclue I have tested your code in my Wing IDE (after adding the missing declaration of `number`, `first`, `last`) and it works whether it is in debug mode or not.

Comment: @acw1668 I'm using a different computer right now but it is working. That was odd